# Replace string with a new value

Tags: unix, awk

I'm trying to manipulate a huge file (+5.000.000 records), so I can replace the value of the 8th column for example.

```
If $8 = 1 replace it with success
if $8 = 2 replace it with check
if $8 = null replace with undefined
```

Here's a piece of the data which is separated by a `,` character:

```
"APPLICATION_ID","ORIGIN_ID","SERVICE_ID","PROVIDER_ID","RATING_ID","ATO","DATE","USER_TYPE","ESTATUS","OPERATION_ID"

"3","2","424","5020","1058","3017292917","30/11/2016 01:14:25 a.m.","1","2004","14804862360104011458"
```

The field I want to replace is `USER_TYPE` located at `$8`

I tried this but it doesn't replace the values:

```
awk '{if($8 = 1) print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, "success", $9, $10}' input_file
```

How can I get this done?

Comment: as below, a single `=` assigns the value on the RHS to the name on the LHS. To test for equality, use `==`, so `if($8==1)...`. You also need to tell `awk` to split fields on the `,` char, with either awk -F, '{...}' file` OR `awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{....}' file`. What happens when there are `,`s inside the dbl-quoted data? Kaboom! ... So much better to use a <tab> char to separate fields in your data file (or maybe `|` char). Good luck.

Comment: When you need to deal with csv, awk is definitely not the good way to go, since it doesn't handle cases where the value contains the delimiter. You should use a tool designed to deal with csv, for example `csvtool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a shorter one-liner:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";a[1]="success";a[2]="check"} {gsub(/"/,"",$8)} $8 in a{$8=a[$8]} 1' input.txt
```

Broken out for commenting:

```
BEGIN {
  FS=OFS=","       # set our field separators
  a[1]="success"   # populate an array with replacement values
  a[2]="check"
}

{
  gsub(/"/,"",$8)   # remove quotes in field 8, for easier processing
}

$8 in a {           # check to see if field 8 is a member of our array
  $8=a[$8]          # replace field 8 with the contents of the array at that index
}

1                   # print the line
```

If it's important to keep the quotes around each field, you can do that by replacing the assignement with a `sprintf()` that includes them:

```
  $8=sprintf("\"%s\"",a[$8])
```

Remember that awk only knows about your field separator, not your quotes. If you have a field that includes a comma inside the quoted field, awk will consider it to be a field separator. You might add protection for this sort of occurrence with something like this at the top of the awk script:

```
NF != 10 { print "ERROR: wrong number of fields in line",NR > "/dev/stderr"; exit(1) }
```

Comment: right on the money, it works perfectly, thank you so much :)

Comment: Yay, glad I could help! :) (I do wonder who downvoted without a comment though.)

Answer (score 1):

@sandatomo: Try(untested):

```
awk -F, -vs1="\"" 'NR>1{gsub(/\"/,"",$8);if($8==1){sub(/.*/,s1 "success" s1,$8)};if($8==2){sub(/.*/,s1 "check" s1,$8)};if($8=="null"){sub(/.*/,s1 "undefined" s1,$8)};print}' OFS=, Input_file
```

**EDIT:** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F, -vs1="\"" 'NR>1{
                                gsub(/\"/,"",$8);
                                if($8==1){
                                                sub(/.*/,s1 "success" s1,$8)
                                         };
                                if($8==2){
                                                sub(/.*/,s1 "check" s1,$8)
                                         };
                                if($8=="null"){
                                                sub(/.*/,s1 "undefined" s1,$8)
                                              };
                                print
                       }
                  ' OFS=,  Input_file
```

EDIT2: I tested my code previous code and it was not having field separator as "," so edited it now.

**EDIT3:** Explanation of above.

```
awk  -F, -vs1="\"" 'NR>1{                                  ##### Setting Field separator as comma(,). Creating a variable named s1 whose value is a quote("). Then Checking here if current line number is greater than 1.
                                                           ##### If above condition is TRUE then all following statements will be executing.
                gsub(/\"/,"",$8);                          ##### substituting all quotes(") in $8 now.
        if($8==1){                                 ##### Check if 8th field value is 1, if yes then it will execute following statement.
                sub(/.*/,s1 "success" s1,$8)     ##### substitute everything in $8 with  s1 "success" s1
                 };
                if($8==2){                                 ##### Similarly like above checking if $8's value is 2
                sub(/.*/,s1 "check" s1,$8)       ##### Then substitute the $8's value with s1 "check" s1
                 };  
                if($8=="null"){                            ##### checking if $8's value is "null" here
                sub(/.*/,s1 "undefined" s1,$8)   ##### substituting the complete value of $8 with s1 "undefined" s1.
                      };
        print                                      ##### printing the whole line now.
         }
    '   OFS=,  Input_file                                  ##### Setting output field separator as a comma. Then mentioning the Input_file here.
```

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 I'll give it a try, thank you :)

Comment: Hello All(MODs), someone has given me a -ve vote on this solution. I would like to request person kindly provide the reason for same. So that I could improve my answer or edit it in case of any mistakes/problems in it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 .. I was granted an equally helpful downvote by some anonymous passer-by as well. These things happen from time to time. Blame the trolls.

Comment: @ghoti: Thank you for letting me know(as I am also kind of new only in stack overflow), I strongly believe we should have a mandate section if someone gives a DOWN vote to someone, then other person has FULL right to know what he/she did wrong in solution so that we could improve ourselves and post/thread too.

Comment: As a convention, that already exists. But as a policy, it would require some sort of enforcement, and therefore a change to the underlying code that runs SO. I am certain this has been discussed before in Meta, but it wouldn't hurt to bring it up there again, as it's a problem that doesn't go away by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
awk  'BEGIN {OFS=FS=",";r["\"\""] = "\"undefined\""; r["\"1\""]= "\"success\""; r["\"2\""]="\"check\""} {if($8 in r ) $8 = r[$8]} 1' input_file
```

**Explanation**

- the `BEGIN` parts sets up a replacement-mapping in `r`. e.g. `r["\"1\""]= "\"success\"";` is a map of the literal token `"1"` (a 1 with the qoutes!) to the literal value `"success"` (also including the quotes!)
- additionally `FS` and `OFS` are set to use comma as input and output separator in the `BEGIN` part
- the part after the definition of `r` consists of a test if the value of the field `$8` is a key in the map, if yes, then the field `$8` is replaced by the value defined in the map `r` for this key
- the question is not 100% clear if there are unmapped values in column `$8`, so use this as a starting point for your own experiments

Comment: probably best to qualify replacement with `$8 in r` otherwise will remove unmatched fields.

Comment: @LarsFischer thank you for your help, I don't know why but with the null fields it didn't work, maybe it's because awk implementation, I'm using a HP-UX unix machine, greetings

Comment: Lars, if you don't set `OFS`, your output will have fields separated by space instead of commas. Also, it would be great if you could explain what your solution actually *does*, so that the OP can learn from your answer more easily.

Comment: @sandatomo Please specify in the question what you mean by `null fields`. Best give an example input and output line. `null field` could mean  anything from `""`, `null`, `"null"` or just the empty string between two commas.

Comment: @LarsFischer, Hi sorry it took me so long to respond in this case the null string was like this "" just doble quotes with nothing in between.